# MYSQL joining two table slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 main table in MYSQL DB. I will call it **entityA** and **entityB**.
There are some logic that user will start to create a **entityA** and then convert it to **entityB** but some time they will not create **entityA** and only create **entityB**
Therefore, I have created a **middle** table which stored **entityAId** and **entityBId**.

| entityAId | entityBId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | null |
| null | 2 |

I need to show them in one list view for user. If there are **entityB**, show the information in **entityB** table and if no **entityB**, show **entityA** information.
What current SQL will be like below:

```
SELECT IFNULL(entityB.colA, entityA.colA), IFNULL(entityB.colB, entity.colB), ....
FROM middle
LEFT JOIN entityA on middle.entityAId = entityA.id
LEFT JOIN entityB on middle.entityBId = entityB.id
WHERE (entityB.colA = "XXX" OR entityA.colA= "XXX") AND ....
ORDER BY IFNULL(entityB.colA, entityA.colA)
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

The SQL become slow when the table become bigger as one customer imported a large amount of historical data.
Can anybody help how to make it faster? I am not sure if it can use by rewriting the SQL or creating some index on it?
Thanks

======== AND SOME MORE FROM COMMENT =========

Currently **middle** table has no id, I just added a unique for **entityAId** and **entityBId**

Below is the Create statement for 3 table:

```
CREATE TABLE `entityA` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `colA` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `colB` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_entityA_party_group_code` (`colA`),
  KEY `idx_entityA_booking_no` (`colB`),
  KEY `idx_entityA_id_partyGroupCode` (`id`,`colA`),
  KEY `idx_entityA_id_moduleTypeCode` (`id`,`colB`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `entityB` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `colA` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `colB` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_entityB_party_group_code` (`colA`),
  KEY `idx_entityB_booking_no` (`colB`),
  KEY `idx_entityB_id_colA` (`id`,`colA`),
  KEY `idx_entityB_id_colB` (`id`,`colB`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `middle` (
  `entityAId` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `entityBId` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_middle_entityAId_entityBId` (`entityAId`,`entityBId`),
  KEY `idx_middle_entityAId (`entityAId`),
  KEY `idx_middle_entityBId` (`entityBId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

====. ADD explain in JSON =====

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "717863.40"
    },
    "nested_loop": [
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "middle",
          "access_type": "index",
          "key": "idx_middle_entityAId_entityBId",
          "used_key_parts": [
            "entityAId",
            "entityBId"
          ],
          "key_length": "18",
          "rows_examined_per_scan": 896658,
          "rows_produced_per_join": 896658,
          "filtered": "100.00",
          "using_index": true,
          "cost_info": {
            "read_cost": "537.00",
            "eval_cost": "89665.80",
            "prefix_cost": "90202.80",
            "data_read_per_join": "20M"
          },
          "used_columns": [
            "entityAId",
            "entityBId"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "entityA",
          "access_type": "eq_ref",
          "possible_keys": [
            "PRIMARY",
            "idx_entityA_id_entityANo",
            "idx_entityA_id_partyGroupCode",
            "idx_entityA_id_moduleTypeCode"
          ],
          "key": "PRIMARY",
          "used_key_parts": [
            "id"
          ],
          "key_length": "8",
          "ref": [
            "db_main.middle.entityAId"
          ],
          "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
          "rows_produced_per_join": 896658,
          "filtered": "100.00",
          "cost_info": {
            "read_cost": "224164.50",
            "eval_cost": "89665.80",
            "prefix_cost": "404033.10",
            "data_read_per_join": "23G"
          },
          "used_columns": [
            "id",
            "partyGroupCode"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "entityB",
          "access_type": "eq_ref",
          "possible_keys": [
            "PRIMARY",
            "idx_entityB_id_partyGroupCode",
            "idx_entityB_id_jobNo",
            "idx_entityB_id_masterNo",
            "idx_entityB_id_houseNo"
          ],
          "key": "PRIMARY",
          "used_key_parts": [
            "id"
          ],
          "key_length": "8",
          "ref": [
            "db_main.middle.entityBId"
          ],
          "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
          "rows_produced_per_join": 896658,
          "filtered": "100.00",
          "cost_info": {
            "read_cost": "224164.50",
            "eval_cost": "89665.80",
            "prefix_cost": "717863.40",
            "data_read_per_join": "27G"
          },
          "used_columns": [
            "id",
            "partyGroupCode"
          ],
          "attached_condition": "<if>(found_match(entityB), (((`db_main`.`entityA`.`id` is not null) or (`db_main`.`entityB`.`id` is not null)) and ((`db_main`.`entityB`.`partyGroupCode` = 'DEV') or (`db_main`.`entityA`.`partyGroupCode` = 'DEV'))), true)"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What's `entityB.colA = ""` supposed to do? Do you store empty strings instead of null in your tables? I'd expect `entityB.colA IS NULL`.

Comment: is there any ID column at middle table?

Comment: Show your table indexes, also show your full where clause.

Comment: This table should have a primary key because it's a mapping table.

Comment: Currently **middle** table has no id, I just added a unique for **entityAId** and **entityBId** and I added the create statement on question

Comment: @KenChan . . . The issue is probably the `order by` and not the `join`s.  You simply have a lot of data that needs to be ordered.

Comment: @GordonLinoff order is one of the requirement and do you have any suggestion

Comment: @KenChan . . . One possibility would be to store `colA` in the middle table and use that for ordering.  But that might be a big change to the data model.

Comment: @basha04 ADD explain JSON in question, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- When you have `PRIMARY KEY(id)`, do not also have `INDEX(id, ...)`.  (Space improvement, not speed.)
- If `middle` is a many-to-many mapping table, I am surprised that either of the columns is declared `NULL`.  Make them `NOT NULL` and follow the indexing instructions in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table  (Speed and space improvements; hard to predict how much improvement.)
- `OR` does not optimize well.  Use a `UNION`:  (Potentially a large speed improvement)

  ```
  ( SELECT  IFNULL(entityB.colA, entityA.colA),
        IFNULL(entityB.colB, entity.colB), ....
    FROM  middle
    LEFT JOIN  entityA  ON middle.entityAId = entityA.id
    LEFT JOIN  entityB  ON middle.entityBId = entityB.id
    WHERE  entityB.colA = "XXX"
      AND  ....
    ORDER BY  IFNULL(entityB.colA, entityA.colA)
    LIMIT  20 )
  UNION
  ( SELECT  IFNULL(entityB.colA, entityA.colA),
        IFNULL(entityB.colB, entity.colB), ....
    FROM  middle
    LEFT JOIN  entityA  ON middle.entityAId = entityA.id
    LEFT JOIN  entityB  ON middle.entityBId = entityB.id
    WHERE  entityA.colA= "XXX"
      AND  ....
    ORDER BY  IFNULL(entityB.colA, entityA.colA)
    LIMIT  20  )
  ORDER BY  IFNULL(entityB.colA, entityA.colA)
  LIMIT  20 OFFSET 0
  ```
- If you will be increasing the `OFFSET`, see this for how to deal with it:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#or
- `UNION ALL` is faster than `UNION DISTINCT` (which is the default).  Use `ALL` if you "XXX" will not show up in both tables.
- `LEFT` is probably unnecessary.  (No speed change.)
- `"rows_examined_per_scan": 896658` may drop to `20` !
- It *may* be possible to store the data so that the relationship always has A < B.  That way, the search could do one Select (without `OR` or `UNION`)  (double speed, but add complexity)  Since you are hiding the "entity", I cannot say whether it would matter.

Comment: Thanks. finally based on your query and I developed a faster query